# Is this sentence correct? “I forgot to brought my money”

Tags: tense, past-tense, infinitives

> I forgot to **brought** my money.

I am an English teacher but I got stranded in this sentence. I know (or I least, I think) it’s more common to say:

> I forgot to **bring** my money.

but I can’t explain why. Or are both verb tenses correct?

Comment: The verb "to forget" is followed by the [*infinitive*](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/) (or the gerund) form of the verb.  *"I forgot to brought"* is not grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

**brought** is the simple past of irregular verb **bring**.

Forget is complemented by an infinitive clause:

> I forgot *to bring my money*.

by a noun-phrase:

> I forgot *my wallet*.
>
> You can forget *going to the party*. You're grounded for a week.

Sometimes that last usage, where **forget** means "abandon your plans", uses the preposition **about**:

> You can forget about going to the party. You're grounded for a week.

or by a prepositional phrase:

> I forgot *about this bar's cover charge*. It's $10.